# How can I write the "?:" statements without using the '?' (question mark)?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-operator

node1 and node2 are nodes of a linked list.

```
Node* node1, Node* node2;
int carry = 0;
int sum;
sum = carry + (node1 ? node1->data : 0) + (node2 ? node2->data : 0);
```

Since `x ? y : z` works like `if(x) y else z`
I tried

```
if (node1 && node2)
 sum = carry + node1->data + node2->data;
else if(node1 && !node2)
 sum = carry + node1->data;
else if(!node1 && node2)
 sum = carry + node2->data;
else if(!node1 && !node2)
 sum = carry;
```

Can we use nodes as if they were booleans like this? If not, how can I write this statement without using the question mark?

Comment: `auto data = [](Node* p, int default_value) { if (p) return p->data; return default_value; };` then use `int sum = carry + data(node1, 0) + data(node2, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

That `? :` is called the [conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) (or sometimes ternary operator in the context of C-like languages). In C++ `x ? y : z` works exactly like `if (x) y else z` except that the `if else` block isn't an expression and doesn't return a value. So if you can use `node ?` then you can use `if (node)`, any numeric expressions can be converted into a boolean expression

However you don't actually to combine the 2 ternary expression and need so many if blocks like that. Just do like how the ternary expression is evaluated

```
sum = carry
if (node1)
    sum += node1->data;
if (node2)
    sum += node2->data;
```

Comment: actually it is the conditional operator. A ternary operator is any operator that takes 3 operands and coincidentally C++ has only one of this kind, but in principle there could be others

Comment: its also not "exactly" like the if, because it evaluates to the common type of the 2nd and 3rd operator, but thats a simplification that is probably ok in this context

Comment: @idclev463035818 For more pedantry, it's certainly true that it "is called" the ternary operator, by many people.

Comment: @aschepler haha, I had the same thoughts, but nitpicking my own nitpick seemed too pathetic ;). I'd add "colloquially", then I am fine with it

Comment: Example for which `if…else` and `? :` differ: Given `struct Blargh { Blargh(int x) { std::cout << "Blargh!\n"; } };`, `0 ? Blargh(0) : 0;` prints “Blargh!” but `if (0) Blargh(0); else 0;` does not.